# How to set the location for a SOAP service in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, web-services, soap

I have successfully generated my web service proxies using the FlexBuilder menus.  This particular web service has an internal (or incorrect) "location" specified in its WSDL.  This means that when I go to make an actual method call, it fails because the DNS name specified in the location field is wrong.  (It shows as "aborted" in fire bug).

How do I set the location attribute on the service object?  I have done this in Java and php before but cannot figure out how to do it in Flex.

---

update:

The field that needs to be changed is listed below.  It is called "WSDL-endpoint."  So the question is:  How do I do this programmatically given the generated web service object (the one that extends WebServiceWrapper)?

```
<annotation name="ServiceConfig">
  <item name="DEFAULT_ENTITY_PACKAGE">valueObjects</item>
  <item name="WSDL-endpoint">http://eoc7/eoc7/api.asmx</item>
  <item name="LINKED_FILE"></item>
</annotation>
```

Comment: Show some code so we can see where you went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the way to programmatically set the "location" of a web service in a Flex SOAP service:

Go to the generated service class and set this property on the _service control object:

```
_serviceControl.endpointURI = "http://uri-to-real-location"
```

So I created a simple method to set this from outside the class:

```
public function setEndpointUri(uri : String) : void 
{
    _serviceControl.endpointURI = uri;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Flash Builder stores webservice address in .fml file in .model subdirectory of your flex project. You can edit this file, then reopen the project. But the easiest way is to remove yor Data/Service and rebuild it using wizard.

Comment: I shouldn't have to edit the address in that file and rebuilding won't help because the problem isn't that the service's url has changed.  the problem is that the URL to the WSDL is different than the location field in the WSDL.  for example, this is how you do it in Java with axis:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243980/how-can-i-change-wsdlsoapaddress-location-at-runtime

Comment: Also, editing that file and reopening the project doesn't work.  I need the cannonical programmatic way to do this

Answer (score 0):

This is the only way I could get it to work, in the generated stub for your service:

```
import com.adobe.fiber.core.model_internal;
```

Also:

```
    /**
 * Override super.init() to provide any initialization customization if needed.
 */
protected override function preInitializeService():void
{           
    _needWSDLLoad = false; // to prevent loading the default WSDL
    super.preInitializeService();
    // Initialization customization goes here
    wsdl = "http://localhost/yourservice?wsdl";
    _needWSDLLoad = true;
    model_internal::loadWSDLIfNecessary();
```